# IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, io

Hello i am trying to get some java to run however i keep getting an error message here's the message: 
`unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown myName = in.readLine();`

```
    import java.io.*;
public class While{
    public static void main(String []args){
        int num = 0;
        while (num != 999){
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            num = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            System.out.println("You typed: " + num);
        }
        System.out.println("999 entered, so the loop has ended.");
    }
}
```

Just going to be straight out, i have not used java and this is my first time ever using it, i was asked by my boss if i can take a look at it so far i've been able to do everything but i cannot fix this error message, any and all help welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surround the code with a `try-catch` statement and move the `BufferedReader` initialization before the `while` loop. Also, make sure to always close the resources after using them.

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    int num = 0;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (num != 999){
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            num = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            System.out.println("You typed: " + num);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle your exception, probably with a message
        //showing a basic example
        System.out.println("Error while reading the data.");
        e.printStacktrace(System.in);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Problem while closing the reader.");
                e.printStacktrace(System.in);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("999 entered, so the loop has ended.");
}
```

If you're using Java 7, then you can leverage all the code by using [try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    int num = 0;
    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        while (num != 999){
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            num = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            System.out.println("You typed: " + num);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle your exception, probably with a message
        //showing a basic example
        System.out.println("Error while reading the data.");
        e.printStacktrace(System.in);
    }
    System.out.println("999 entered, so the loop has ended.");
}
```

Comment: empty catch is very very very bad

Comment: @OliverWatkins answer updated to show how to handle an exception.

Comment: In general when I have determined that an exception is (as far as I know) not going to happen I rethrow a RuntimeException, so if the Exception really does happen at least the application falls over with a decent exception rather than doing something "suprising". (NB; i'm not the downvoter either)

Comment: I get 9 errors with this 
all class, interface, or enum expected
I'll work on getting this error fixed, thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza in.close() requires also a try/catch.

Comment: why not just add 'throws Exception' on the main method? Does the same thing @RichardTingle

Comment: @OliverWatkins that's a design matter. IMO I prefer to teach Java in the right way so no letting the Exception just propagate (even if it won't happen).

Comment: according to Java, being able to 'propogate the exception' is the right way. No idea what 'right way' you are talking about

Comment: @OliverWatkins Of course then you have to deal with it on a higher level, my solution is for when a class you've used could have returned an exception (eg a matrix class that requires square matricies returns an exception if its non square) but in your case you *believe* it will always go through without a problem so you effectively empty catch it, but the RuntimeException is there just in case you're wrong

Comment: @OliverWatkins You should deal with an exception as soon as possible, if it can't be delt with on this level; then and only then propogate it. If it can never be dealt with then throw a RuntimeException

Comment: @RichardTingle answer updated showing Java 7 code that will free from using lot of try/catch in the code. And from the *I prefer to throw an Exception instead*, that's a matter of design, which is not the main issue here.